# DocuSign RESOURCE NOT FOUND error

Tags: docusignapi

I am now getting this error.  An email is sent to me requesting my signature.  When I click on the VIEW DOCUMENTS button, I get a "This Connection is Untrusted" screen which cannot be bypassed.  If I go to docusign.com and click the ACCESS DOCUMENTS link, I am requested for the SECURITY CODE which I enter and receive the message "An invalid email document code was entered. Please try again."

The code now shows:

```
            Dim docFile As String = "" + docName.Substring(41, (docName.Length() - 41)) + "\" + ""
        'Overwrite the default content-type header and set a boundary marker
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY"
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False
        request.KeepAlive = False

        'Start building the multipart request body
        Dim asciLN As String = Chr(10)
        Dim asciCR As String = Chr(13)

        Dim requestBodyStart As String = asciCR + asciLN + asciCR + asciLN + "--BOUNDARY" + asciCR + asciLN + _
            "Content-Type: application/xml" + asciCR + asciLN + _
            "Content-Disposition: form-data" + asciCR + asciLN + _
            asciCR + asciLN + _
            xmlBody + asciCR + asciLN + asciCR + asciLN + "--BOUNDARY" + asciCR + asciLN + _
            "Content-Type: application/pdf" + asciCR + asciLN + _
            "Content-Disposition: file; filename=\" + docFile + ";  documentId=1" + asciCR + asciLN + _
             asciCR + asciLN
        Dim requestBodyEnd As String = asciCR + asciLN + "--BOUNDARY--" + asciCR + asciLN + asciCR + asciLN
```

Producing a REQUEST:

```
        --BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data

<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi"><status>sent</status><emailSubject>DocuSign API - Embedded Signing example</emailSubject><documents><document><documentId>1</documentId><name>\\10.1.11.100\SecureDocs\EnrollmentForms\CrystalReport1.pdf</name></document></documents><recipients><signers><signer><recipientId>1</recipientId><email>hmitchell@ata.edu</email><name>Alexandra Adams</name><tabs><signHereTabs><signHere><xPosition>100</xPosition><yPosition>100</yPosition><documentId>1</documentId><pageNumber>1</pageNumber></signHere></signHereTabs></tabs></signer></signers></recipients></envelopeDefinition>

--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"CrystalReport1.pdf\";  documentId=1

%PDF-1.7 
%���� 
1 0 obj 
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R 
/PageMode /UseNone 
/ViewerPreferences << 
/FitWindow true 
/PageLayout /SinglePage 
/NonFullScreenPageMode /UseNone
```

Can anyone see a problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're importing the PDF but not the contents. You need to base64 encode it or get the contents itself.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, for the sake of brevity, I did not include all of the encoding in my post.  The document would not display in FIrefox but would in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I can think of.  First off, I see in the `documents` element of the XML you're constructing you have this:

```
<documents>
  <document>
     <documentId>1</documentId>
     <name>\\10.1.11.100\SecureDocs\EnrollmentForms\CrystalReport1.pdf</name>
  </document>
```

I don't believe you can have backslash (\) characters in a filename as the system would think it's a directory path.  Try simply this instead:

```
<name>CrystalReport1.pdf</name>
```

Next, usually the Resource not found errors are related to the full URL you are using as your endpoint.  Since you have not specified that I'm not sure if that's the problem, but which endpoint are you hitting?  I believe it should be:

```
http://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

So if you are working on an integration in your developer sandbox and using version 2 of the REST API and your account id is 12345 then it should be:

```
http://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/12345/envelopes
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Ergin, my URL looks exactlly like you say it should. Update: if I open the emailed link in IE, the document is presented for signing, but I still get the RESOURCE NOT FOUND in the reply.

Comment: I am receiving the error on the <recipientViewRequest>.  Here is the request: (Next Comment)

Comment: POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/111/views/recipient HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: 
<DocuSignCredentials>
<Username>m@ata.edu</Username>
<Password>x</Password>
<IntegratorKey>i</IntegratorKey>
</DocuSignCredentials>
Accept:application/xml
Content-Type:application/xml
Host:demo.docusign.net
Content-Length:280

<recipientViewRequest xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<authenticationMethod>email</authenticationMethod>
<email>m@ata.edu</email>
<returnUrl>http://www.docusign.com</returnUrl>
<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
<userName>AA</userName>
</recipientViewRequest>

Comment: Here is the code:                xmlBody = "<recipientViewRequest xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi""> " + _
                  "<authenticationMethod>email</authenticationMethod>" + _
                  "<email>" + email + "</email>" + _
                  "<returnUrl>http://www.docusign.com</returnUrl>" + _
                  "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" + _
                  "<userName>" + recipientName + "</userName>" + _
                  "</recipientViewRequest>"

Comment: If I want to add comments to my own question that exceed the comments limit, should I click ANSWER YOUR QUESTION?

Comment: Hugh, if I trust that the above is your POST - You can't have "Account" 111.

Comment: Also, please note you must specify the clientUserId you will use in the recipient view when you "Send" the envelope, and I didn't see that in the XML above.

Comment: Also, as mentioned before on your other SO question, think in these terms with Stack Overflow - 1 question = 1 Answer. As you get answers that fix an issue, reword the question to match the first answer that corrects it. Then create a new question for the next question, otherwise the value to others is reduced. In this case of your "example", it has several problems as noted and this makes it difficult to tell what has been fixed and what is still the problem. Hope this helps